# PAYPAL API: how to search transactions by payee's email

Tags: paypal

for my project I'm trying to list my end user's transactions when they log into my app. I want to get all the transactions for a user by their email (because it's the most unique identifier I have for them). I've looked through the paypal api docs for a way to search transactions by a payee's email via the  `/v1/reporting/transactions` but I don't see any parameters that would allow that.

Am I missing something? is there really no way to search paypal for transactions by payee's email (or any payee info for that matter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way. Keep a record of completed transactions in your own database.

For past transactions, the user can do an Activity Download of a CSV file from their account which you can import.